# How to reorder DOM flow

Tags: javascript, jquery, layout, flexbox

I have the following layout problem.  4 blocks one after the other a1,b1,a2,b2 in a column on mobile.
On the desktop I want to get a1,a2,b1-b2 that is a1 followed by a2 followed by b1-b2 on same row but below a2.  I was hoping to use flexbox but not sure how to go about this.

mobile:

```
<div style='display:flex;flex-direction:column>
    <div id='a1'></div>
    <div id='b1'></div>
    <div id='a2'></div>         //each of these is 100VW
    <div id='b2'></div>
 </div>
```

desktop:

```
    <div id='a1'></div>      // the first two are 100vw
    <div id='a2'></div>
    <div id='b1'></div><div id='b2'></div>  //each of these would be 50vw
```

Is there a way to do this with one version of the html and only modifying the css?

Comment: You're dealing in 2 dimensions, not 1, so look to Grid not Flexbox.

Comment: This is about CSS and not the DOM. CSS has no effect on the DOM. You have also tagged this as jquery and javascript. Why?

Comment: @Rob, clearly it's about both.  We need to change the flow from a1,b1,a2,b2 to a1,a2,b1,b2

Comment: Well, neither flex nor any other CSS properties will change the DOM flow.

Comment: @Quentin, I see I can individually place each cell - is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grid would be simpler, but it's also possible with flexbox.

### flex

```css
article {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#a1 { order: 1; }
#a2 { order: 2; }
#b1 { order: 3; }
#b2 { order: 4; }

div {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#b1, #b2 {
  flex: 1 0 34%; /* allows max 2 items per row, with ample space for margins */
}

#b2 {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

@media ( max-width: 500px) {
  article {
    display: block;
  }
  #b2 {
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<article>
  <div id='a1'>a1</div>
  <div id='b1'>b1</div>
  <div id='a2'>a2</div>
  <div id='b2'>b2</div>
</article>
```

[jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kj0hospr/)

---

### grid

```css
article {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  grid-template-areas:
    " a1 a1 "
    " a2 a2 "
    " b1 b2 "
}

#a1 {
  grid-area: a1;
}

#a2 {
  grid-area: a2;
}

#b1 {
  grid-area: b1;
}

#b2 {
  grid-area: b2;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  article {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-areas:
      "a1""b1""a2""b2";
  }
}

div {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <div id='a1'>a1</div>
  <div id='b1'>b1</div>
  <div id='a2'>a2</div>
  <div id='b2'>b2</div>
</article>
```

[jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/m1f8uL96/1/)

Comment: Just forgot the add the `order` property. Sorry. Will update now.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the order property in flexbox.

Comment: No problem. Here's an [explanation of the `order` property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36118012/3597276).

Comment: really helpful.  Appreciate seeing the answer both ways.